# change distance of x-axis labels from axis in sciplot bargraph

Tags: r, graphics

I'm constructing a plot using bargraph.CI from sciplot. The x-axis represents a categorical variable, so the values of this variable are the names for the different positions on the x-axis. Unfortunately these names are long, so at default settings, some of them just disappear. I solved this problem by splitting them into multiple lines by injecting "\n" where needed. This basically worked, but because the names are now multi-line, they look too close to the x-axis. I need to move them farther away. How?

I know I can do this with mgp, but that affects the y-axis too.

I know I can set axisnames=FALSE in my call to barplot.CI, then use axis to create a separate x-axis. (In fact, I'm already doing that, but only to make the x-axis extend farther than it would by default- see my code below.) Then I could give the x-axis its own mgp parameter that would not affect the y-axis. But as far as I can tell, axis() is well set up for ordinal or continuous variables and doesn't seem to work great for categorical variables. After some fiddling, I couldn't get it to put the names in the right locations (i.e. right under their correspondence bars)

Finally, I tried using mgp.axis.labels from Hmisc to set ONLY the x-axis mgp, which is precisely what I want, but as far as I could tell it had no effect on anything.

Ideas? Here's my code.

```
ylim    = c(0.5,0.8)
yticks  = seq(ylim[1],ylim[2],0.1)
ylab    = paste(100*yticks,"%",sep="")

bargraph.CI( 
    response    = D$accuracy,
    ylab        = "% Accuracy on Test",
    ylim        = ylim,
    x.factor    = D$training,
    xlab        = "Training Condition",
    axes        = FALSE
    )
axis(
    side        = 1,
    pos         = ylim[1],
    at          = c(0,7),
    tick        = TRUE,
    labels      = FALSE
    )
axis(
    side        = 2,
    tick        = TRUE,
    at          = yticks,
    labels      = ylab,
    las         = 1
    )
```

Comment: If people can reproduce your code on their system you'll stand a better chance of getting a(n) (good) answer. We do not have access to `D` so cannot reproduce this code. Have a look at `dput()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axis` works fine with cateory but you should set the right ticks values and play with `pos` parameter for offset translation. Here I use `xvals` the return value of `bargraph.CI` to set `àxis` tick marks.

Here a reproducible example:

[image]

```
library(sciplot)
# I am using some sciplot data 
dat <- ToothGrowth
### I create along labels
labels <- c('aaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaa\nhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh',
          'bbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbbb\nhhhhhhhhhhhhhh',
          'cccccccccc\nccccccccccc\ngdgdgdgdgd')
## I change factor labels
dat$dose <- factor(dat$dose,labels=labels)
ll <- bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = dat,axisnames=FALSE) 
## set at to xvals
axis(side=1,at=ll$xvals,labels=labels,pos=-2,tick=FALSE)
```